Exposing DSpace frontend and backend in localhost to te www
As a test version i need to make my DSpace library accessible from the web without proper hosting, i set up a nginx reverse proxy an tried to use localtunnel to generate e web link, however i get the 500 server error. What am I doing wrong?
Since my internet provider can't give me a public IP adress I cannot just port-forward, as I introduced I tried a nginx reverse proxy but i think there are some problems in the DSpace configuartion. As long as i go to localhost everything works fine, but when I try to access it from the localtunnel link i get the 500 server error. I think it has something to do with the way the backend and frontend are connected, but shoudn't the proxy deal with that?
I'm nowhere near a network expert, just a student of non-IT things that has a minimum of comprehnsion on how computer work, so I don'r really know what I'm doing.
